# RegEx для ввода ФИО с необязательной частью

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как в данном случае правильно указать необязательную группу для ввода, а именно, второе слово в отчестве. Допустим, чаще всего встречается Иванов Иван Иванович, но может быть Иванов Иван Иван оглы.
Как сделать так, чтоб (оглы) было необязательной частью для ввода тут:

```
^[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+$
```

Ставлю вопросительный знак, как указание на необязательную часть, но тогда все ломается.

Comment: В именах и фамилиях также могут быть и тире, и апострофы, да и регистр в составных именах и фамилиях пляшет... помрёшь ты регулярку на каждый чих составлять.

Comment: @Akina А в данном случае как корректно убрать последнюю группу из обязательных для ввода?

Comment: @Ксения попробуйте так `^[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+(?:\s[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+){2,3}$`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
^[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+(?:\s[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+(?:\s[а-яё]+)?)?$
                             ^------------------^^----------^^^
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/WQZrwr/1)